# How to calculate the expected value of a function of a Poisson variable

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value

Let $Y \sim Poisson(\lambda)$, and $f(Y)$ is a function of $Y$. Is there a general method, either analytically or numerically, for calculating the expected value of $f(Y)$? In other words, I would like to calculate (or approximate) the following function:

$$
\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} f(y) \cdot \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} e^{-\lambda}
$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: numerically there are at least two: 1. compute the partial sums of the expectation equation; 2. use monte carlo method. But the difficulty is how to gauge and control the accuracy of the approximation --- this will depend on what your function is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain further or give some materials for me to read about the partial sums and the monte carlo methods for this question? As for the function $f(y)$, if it is the PDF of normal distribution where the mean is y, how do we compute the expected value? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This form of sum is a Poisson generating function, which can also be framed in more common parlance as an [exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function):

$$\mathbb{E}(f(y)) = \sum_{y=0}^\infty f(y) \cdot \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} e^{-\lambda} = \sum_{y=0}^\infty a_y \frac{\lambda^y}{y!},$$

where the series $\{ a_y \}$ is defined by $a_y \equiv f(y) \cdot e^{-y}$.  There is no general closed form for this sum that holds for all functions $f$, but particular forms of exponential generating functions can be written in closed form.

There is a large mathematical literature on the properties and use of generating functions, and techniques to manipulate these functions.  The particular technique to evaluate your series would depend on the function $f$, so without specifying this function there is nothing more that can be established other than general results for exponential generating functions.